# if $match returns null insert doc (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i want to do the following aggregation query.. if the doc exists in the collection then let exists be true else make it false

```
$project: {
    "Exists": {
        {
            $switch: {
                branches: [
                    { case: { "if $match did not return null " }, then: true }
                ],
            default: false
        }
    }
}
```

the reason i'm doing this is that im hoping to use this information later to insert into the collection if the document does not exist.. i am open to suggestions if this can be done in a better way as its starting to look like this is not the way to go... can $upsert be used in this case?

Comment: You can just use `$upsert`. I believe it works even for sharded collection. Better to use that rather than implementing your own workaround.

Comment: do you know where would upsert go though? $match only takes a query as an arg..